# Error showing in the React when tried to add counterup js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6, counter

I have faced a problem. I have used `"jquery.counterup": "^2.1.0"` in my react project. But showing some errors. I am new in this environment. I have tried but can't be understood why showing these errors? Also, a similar error is showing when I have tried to add owl-carousel.
[CounterUp NPM Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/counterup)
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import CountUp from "jquery.counterup";

class FunFactCOunter extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Counter
        $(".count").CountUp({
            delay: 20,
            time: 1500
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <span className="count">500</span>K
                <span className="count">450</span>K
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default FunFactCOunter;
```

**dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery.counterup": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-icofont": "0.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Please see this `https://a.uguu.se/1wyGx3aQZlJz_jquery.counterup.min.js`

Comment: Did you added the `<script>` [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/counterup#usage) in you html code ?

Comment: I think that you don't need to import CountUp. Just remove 3rd line.

Comment: @J.Doe then showing this error `Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).counterUp is not a function
` and its too long errors

Comment: @R.García yes added waypoints. I have added the dependencies code please check.